# document.addEventListener slows down loading

Tags: javascript, event-handling, slowdown, performance

I have a Web App. I have written a Calendar javascript code. A script tag is in body of html code loads that js file from server.

Until writing the last codes, loading page was taking around 900 ms. When I wrote last of my javascript codes, it takes 6 seconds loading the page.

Javascript code basically defines a class for my calendar. It has lots of methods in it. In my last codes, I wrote a new method which is like below:

```
registerHider = function(){
    alert('hello');

    if(document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener('click', hider, false);
    }
};
```

The method "hider" is another method which just changes "display" style to "none". That's all. When I comment out "addEventListener" code, page loads around 900ms again. But when I uncomment is it takes 6 secs again.

I put there an alert to see if page tries to process any code there on load, but no message comes to screen. From there I understand, codes are not executed yet. Even I changed code to register the event only if document is ready, no help, still same.

What can be the reason of this problem?

Comment: any live example just for debugging?

Comment: any way I will suggest to add the event to the target object, not to the whole document

Comment: There is no way adding one event listener to the page causes load time to jump. You have something else [big loop] or tons of DOM look ups/writes that is slowing down the rendering speed.

Comment: @sabithpocker if you bind the event to the whole document, everywhere you click you will get that event fired (at exception for those elements where event is captured and a stopPropagation is done)

Comment: @albanx Exactly. And you can see that as an advantage: it allows you to bind events intended for objects that do not exist in the DOM at the time of the binding, as long as you check the event target inside the listener. That's known as event delegation.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, it could be a good idea, but there one should care about the target of the event. jQuery .on and .live are really helpful in this case.

Comment: @bfavaretto so the optimal solution is to bind listener to the first static parent of the dynamic elemnt?

Comment: @albanx Yes, that's what jQuery `.on` and `.live` (deprecated!) do, behind the scenes.

Comment: @sabithpocker That's a possiblity, but the most efficient solution depends on the event, and on what's on the DOM. I don't see much of a problem in binding all click events to `document` if there are not so many elements on the page. Or the change event, unless your page has 100's of select elements. But I'd avoid binding mousemove to document...

Comment: I couldn't have had the same effect on a simple example. So I uploaded pictures. http://imgur.com/a/aHeNx . There are 4 pictures. Uncommented and commented codes and timings. THERE IS NO CHANGE IN CODES EXCEPT SHOWED COMMENTINGS.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes even i think its dependent on sitution, but they depricated live as it always bound to document. Problems of framework devs not ours always!

Comment: BTW, file name is widget-calendar.js

Comment: How many times are you calling registerHider in your code

Comment: It is called only once when I click into "input" element. onfocus event calls the method "show". Then the method "show" calls "registerHider" method. While codes are uncommented, it takes time for loading, but hiding (connected to document.onclick) and showing the calendar works flawlessly and CPU usage is very normal.

Comment: Can you log time? One at beginning of file in header, one as last script just before body end tag. Use console.time. Adjust the timelogger to spot the code using up your time.

Comment: [22:53:27.695] beforewidget: timer started
[22:53:27.799] beforewidget: 104ms
[22:53:27.861] widget: timer started
[22:53:33.155] widget: 5294ms
[22:53:33.198] afterwidget: timer started
[22:53:33.203] afterwidget: 5ms

Comment: Well, I discovered something. I'm using Firefox 16's debugger now. It shows loaded javascript files in dropbox. When I select other javascript files from list, it loads the codes into text area very quickly. But while loading widget, it waits 3-4 seconds saying "Loading...".

Comment: Did youchecj in chrome or safari? Also move the timer inside widget to find which part is causing trouble. Firefox profiler can also help.

Comment: Well I think, I have solved the problem. What I have done is instead of defining methods for register and unregister, I removed them and written their codes directly into "show" and "hide" methods. Now it loads the page in 1.2secs. But that is still 300ms longer than normal.

Comment: FYI, I also removed "attachEvent" methods from there as well, so it loads quickly. Else, in its new format with "attachEvent" method, it still takes long time. I will install Chrome on VM and try it.

Comment: I tried it on Chrome. While it loads on Firefox, Chrome says it is failed to load the script. But then comment those addEventListener and attachEvent, and Chrome loads it successfully. This started giving me headache. I don't know if it is a bug or something like that.

Comment: You probably have some circular loop eating up memory or something. Get out of your logic of attaching events on onfocus, check attaching everything right when page loads serially, to check if your logic caused any loops or leaks.

Comment: All problems are solved. It has turned out that it wasn't about any of those javascript codes. Lessons learned: If HTTP header's content-length is higher than content's real size; 1) Firefox waits longer but it still works. 2) Chrome fails to load the javascript code. Thanks anyway to everybody attended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems are solved. It has turned out that it wasn't about any of those javascript codes.

Lessons learned: If HTTP header's content-length is higher than content's real size;

1. Firefox waits longer but it still works.
2. Chrome fails to load the javascript code. So it doesn't work.

Thanks anyway to everybody attended.